# Word-guessing game: trying to build an AI

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create a little game.

The rules are very straightforward: you give an English word, and the computer will try to guess this word letter by letter.

The thing is, I'm trying to make the computer guess the letters in a smart way. Let me give you a simple example of what I'm trying to build so you can understand:

1. You give the word "cat" to the computer to guess.
2. The 130K words list I have is narrowed to only the words who have 3 characters, which makes up to 805 words only. And from this list of words, an alphabet is created, containing only 25 letters (not the whole 26) because the new 805 words list contains all the letters of the alphabet but the "z". So we now have a list containing 25 (different) letters.

-- As I can't upload anything here on SO, we will say for this example that the massive 130K words list is a 10 words list (variable name "fullDice") --

> If you try to run my code, pick a word from inside this list or else
>   it's not going to work

3. The computer now guesses a random letter from this 25 letters list.
4. If the letter is not in the word, he doesn't do anything and re-guess a letter from the list.
5. But if the letter is in the word, **that's where things become more complicated**. Let's say the computer guess the letter "c". I want the computer to re-narrow the possible words list, to only those having a "c" in the first character. That way, the 805-words list become now an only 36 words list. Because there are only 36 words who are 3 characters and starts with a "c", a new alphabet is created. And the new alphabet is now made of only 14 letters, making it easier for the computer to guess the next letter and be correct about it. And so on until he finds all the letters.

I'm stuck on part 5. If you try to run my code just below, you'll see that the dictionnary list is never narrowed. That's my problem.

```
import time
from random import randint

fullDice = ["panda", "tiger", "cat", "elephant", "whale", "leopard", "gorilla", "fish", "snake", "eagle"]

askForWord = input("Please enter an english word:   ")

while True:

    updatedDice = []

    for k in range (0, len(fullDice)):
        if len(askForWord) == len(fullDice[k]):
            updatedDice += [fullDice[k]]

    alphabet = []

    for i in range (0, len(updatedDice)):
        for n in range (0, len(updatedDice[i])):
            if updatedDice[i][n] not in alphabet:
                alphabet += [updatedDice[i][n]]

    guessRandomLetter = alphabet[randint(0, len(alphabet) - 1)]

    print("I guess the letter:   " + guessRandomLetter)
    print("From this dice: " + str(len(updatedDice)))
    print("From this amount of letters: " + str(len(alphabet)) + "\n")

    time.sleep(0.75)

    guessedWordUnderlined = "_" * len(askForWord)

    if guessRandomLetter in askForWord:

        for m in range(0, len(askForWord)):
            if askForWord[m] == guessRandomLetter:  # CHECKING IF THE GUESSED LETTER IS INSIDE THE WORD
                guessedWordUnderlined = list(guessedWordUnderlined)
                guessedWordUnderlined[m] = guessRandomLetter

        guessedWordUnderlined = ''.join(map(str, guessedWordUnderlined))

        if guessedWordUnderlined == askForWord:  # CHECK IF USER HAS WON

            print("YOU WON")
            break
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: No. I'm not really experienced in Python, could you please explain me the point and how to do it? By the way, the code produces no error messages, that would be too easy, the error is a logic error.

Comment: Try placing `print` statements around the show the value of different variables that you suspect mount be wrong. This is called "Print debigging", and it's useful for quickly debigging small, simple programs.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, I tried that, it didn't really helped.. :(

Comment: Then you must not have been looking in the right place. If the output is wrong, one of the values that contribute to the output must be wrong.

Comment: You see in my code these two lines :                                                                  **print("From this dice: " + str(len(updatedDice)))
    ---------- print("From this amount of letters: " + str(len(alphabet)) + "\n")**. I tried that, so why is the length of the dice and the alphabet not going down?

Answer (score 0):

you just asked a qs including that code.
i tryed to make it work only with the available words in the dictionnary you gave as "python".

```
    from random import randint
    import random
    import time
    import datetime
    random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

    wordOfTheUser = input("ENTER ENGLISH WORD HERE:  ")
    if wordOfTheUser in ("abracadabra", "python", "coding", "soup", "paper", "list", "leader", "program", "software", "eating","abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
            pass
    else:
            print("your word is not on the list, still devlopping.")
            raise

    diceList1 = ["abracadabra", "python", "coding", "soup", "paper", "list", "leader", "program", "software", "eating","abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]

    diceList2 = []

    for k in range (0, len(diceList1) - 1):
        if len(diceList1[k]) == len(wordOfTheUser):
            diceList2 += [diceList1[k]]

    makeAlphabet = []

    for b in range (0, len(diceList2)):
        for x in range (0, len(diceList2[b])):
            if diceList2[b][x] not in makeAlphabet:
                makeAlphabet += [diceList2[b][x]]

    computerWordSize = "_" * int(len(wordOfTheUser))
    a= len(makeAlphabet)

    while True:

        try:
            randomIndex = randint(0, a)
        except ValueError:

            randomIndex = randint(0, a)
            pass

        try:
            letterChosenRandomly = makeAlphabet[randomIndex]

        except IndexError as e:
            try:
                randomIndex = randint(0, int(len(makeAlphabet)))
                letterChosenRandomly = makeAlphabet[randomIndex]
            except:
                pass

        print("I guess the letter -> " + letterChosenRandomly)

        diceList3 = []

        if letterChosenRandomly in wordOfTheUser:

            print("\n=== WON ===> " + letterChosenRandomly)
            print("=== ALPHABET ===> " + str(len(makeAlphabet)))
            print("=== HDW1 ===> " + str(len(diceList1)))
            print("=== hdw2 ===> " + str(len(diceList2)))
            print("=== hdw3 ===> " + str(len(diceList3)) + "\n\n")
            k=-1


            makeAlphabet = []


            for i in range (0, len(wordOfTheUser) ):
                if letterChosenRandomly == wordOfTheUser[i]:
                    computerWordSize = list(computerWordSize)
                    computerWordSize[i] = letterChosenRandomly

                    for l in range (0, len(diceList2)):
                        if computerWordSize[i] == diceList2[l][i]:
                            diceList3 += [diceList2[l]]

                    for d in range(0, len(diceList3)):
                        for h in range(0, len(diceList2[b])):
                            if diceList2[d][h] not in makeAlphabet:
                                makeAlphabet += [diceList2[d][h]]

            won = False

            computerWordSize = ''.join(map(str, computerWordSize))

            print(computerWordSize)

            if computerWordSize == wordOfTheUser:
                won = True

            if won is True:
                print("YOU WON")
                break

            time.sleep(1)

        else:

            print("\n=== LOOSE ===> " + letterChosenRandomly)
            print("=== ALPHABET ===> " + str(len(makeAlphabet)))
            print("=== HDW1 ===> " + str(len(diceList1)))
            print("== hdw2 ===> " + str(len(diceList2)))
            print("=== hdw3 ===> " + str(len(diceList3)) + "\n\n")
            try:
                makeAlphabet.remove(letterChosenRandomly)
            except:
                print ("Letters not in list")
                break
            k=0

            diceList3 = []

            for q in range (0, len(wordOfTheUser) - 1):
                for l in range(0, len(diceList2)):
                    if computerWordSize[q] == diceList2[l][q]:
                        diceList3 += [diceList2[l]]

            for d in range(0, len(diceList3)):
                for h in range(0, len(diceList2[b])):
                    try:
                        if diceList2[d][h] not in makeAlphabet:
                            makeAlphabet += [diceList2[d][h]]
                    except:
                        try:
                            for s in range(0, len(diceList3)):
                                for f in range(0, len(diceList2)):
                                    if diceList2[s][f] not in makeAlphabet:
                                        makeAlphabet += [diceList2[s][f]]
                        except:
                            ("your word is too short")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: hey, thank you for trying to help me but this code still doesn't work as intended. The alphabet and the list of words are not narrowed each time the  computer guess a letter. If you still wanna help, try to look at my actual code just above, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `if guessedWordUnderlined in askForWord` will never be true. The `in` operator tests whether the first operator is within the second argument, which is a container, such as a list or string. `"_" * len(askForWord)`, the value of `guessedWordUnderlined`, is a string of underscores, and you are testing whether or not that is in `askForWOrd`. If the vale of `askForWord` is `cat`, `askForWord` can be thought of as `["c", "a", "t"]`, so the in operator will be testing `"___" == "c" or "___" == "a" or "___" == "t"`, none of which will be true. This means that the code beneath it will never execute, so the code just repeats forever, randomly guessing letters within the word. I cannot really tell what the function of this `if` is, as you already know each letter you could have chosen is in `askForWord`, though I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

As an aside, you frequently use a construction similar to `for x in range(0, len(LIST): ... LIST[x]`, which can be more concisely and obviously written as `for x in LIST: ... x`. For example, your code

```
for k in range (0, len(fullDice)):
    if len(askForWord) == len(fullDice[k]):
        updatedDice += [fullDice[k]]

alphabet = []
```

could be written as

```
for k in fullDice:
    if len(askForWord) == len(k):
        updatedDice += [k] # This should be updatedDice.append(k), but I
                           # have left it as-is for simplicity's sake.

alphabet = []
```

which should help your code become more readable. There are a few other edits that could be made to make your code more pythonic, but aside from that line I cannot see anything functionally wrong with it. If you share what this `if` is supposed to help, it might make it a bit easier to find any other errors in your code. I hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help! As for the if statement, this was a dumb error from me, I changed it soon after posting it here on SO, but you probably were looking at the code before. Anyway, I've changed it to **if guessRandomLetter in askForWord:** as I want to know if the letter is inside the word before running the following code. also thank you for the "pythonic way to python" little lesson =)

Comment: @Michael You probably don't need that `if`, because your code selects a random letter from the word (given that `alphabet` contains a list of the unique characters in `askForWord`), so it'll allways evaluate to `True`, but it should work fine.

Comment: No, alphabet contains a list of unique characters from the whole list of words.

Comment: @Michael My mistake, sorry; I've been trying it on `cat`, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Having reviewed your code again, I believe the problem is in the statement `guessedWordUnderlined = "_" * len(askForWord)`. This creates a string of underscores whose length is equal to that of `askFOrWord`. The problem is that each at each iteration of the `while True:` loop, a *new* string. This means that at each iteration, the string becomes a list of underscores with one correct letter, but in the next iteration it is overridden. To fix this, you should move the line `guessedWordUnderlined = "_" * len(askForWord)` from its current location to directly below `askForWord = input("Please enter an english word:   ")`. This will mean that it is present in the global scope rather than the local scope, meaning it won't get overwritten. You should also put the line `global guessedWordUnderlined` at the beginning of the `while` loop, if I'm not mistaken. This may require you to rework some code. Hope this works for you!

Comment: I tried it, it didn't really change anything to be honest. The final goal is to narrow the 2 main lists (alphabet and updatedDice) at each loop.

Comment: Instead of the test you do now, then, perhaps you could chose a random letter `guessRandomLetter` and test it with `guessRandomLetter in askForWord` to test if the letter appears within the word and go from there. You might want to look at `string.index` if you go the way I suggested. Other than that, I'm afraid that with the current information, I'm not sure if there's much I can do.